# Multiple Azure Local Network Gateways that aren't connected to eachother

Tags: azure, networking, local, gateway

I'd like to setup a VPN connection from my office towards Azure.
The Azure environment should also contain Local Network Gateways for every customer that we're working towards.

My first question is: Will my customers be able to reach eachothers networks if they are connected to the same Local Network Gateway? If Yes, will this be prevented by creating seperate Local Network Gateways for every customer?

Answer (score 1):

The Local network gateway represents the public IP address of the local VPN device. If all customers are connected to the same VPN device. It's possible that they are connected.

There are Policy-based and route-based VPN devices in Azure. [The document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-connect-multiple-policybased-rm-ps) has clarified that the on-premises networks connecting through **policy-based** VPN devices with this mechanism can only connect to the Azure virtual network; **they cannot transit to other on-premises networks or virtual networks via the same Azure VPN gateway**. If you are using route-based VPN devices, you may configure firewall rules on the on-premise network to restrict the networking traffic from one on-premise network to another on-premise network.